# Error: in oracle plsql of decode: PLS-00382: expression is of wrong type

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql, decode

Question:
Your block should read in two real numbers and tell whether the product of the
two numbers is equal to or greater than 100. Display the output on the screen
using dbms_output.put_line. (Use decode instead of IF statement where
required). Data has to be input by the user.

I am trying this on oracle plsql and getting stuck here.

Code:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE two
AS
    i number;
    j number;
    p number;
    b boolean;
    msg varchar2(100);
BEGIN
    i:=&x;
    j:=&y;
    p:=i*j;
    b:=p>=100;
    select DECODE(b,1,'True','False') into msg from dual;
    dbms_output.put_line(msg);
END;
```

Error:

```
LINE/COL ERROR
-------- -----------------------------------------------------------------
13/16    PLS-00382: expression is of wrong type
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I am not wrong you can't use boolean like that. But if you can transform it into an arithmetic operation resulting into an integer value you got what you want. So try to subtract 100 from p and check whether it's a positive number or not. If it's a positive number p is greater than  100.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE two
AS
    i number;
    j number;
    p number;

    msg varchar2(100);
BEGIN
    i:=&x;
    j:=&y;
    p:=i*j;

    select DECODE(sign(p-100),1,'True','False') into msg from dual;
    dbms_output.put_line(msg);
END;
```

Comment: yes but we have to use only decode?

Comment: @PrajwalDhage I have changed my answer. Hope it's good for your. Best wishes.

Comment: You are not using the `b` variable so both lines using `b` can be removed from the procedure. Additionally, substitution variables are evaluated at compile time and will not be re-evaluated at runtime.

Comment: @MT0 you are right. I should have removed those useless lines. Edited my answer. Thanks.

Comment: The requirement says "Data has to be input by the user", not by the developer. That would seem to rule out substitution variables.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot use substitution variables in a procedure (as they will be evaluated when the procedure is compiled and not when the procedure is run). You need to use arguments for the procedure:

```sql
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE two(
  i IN NUMBER,
  j IN NUMBER
)
AS
BEGIN
  DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(CASE WHEN i * j >= 100 THEN 'True' ELSE 'False' END);
END;
/
```

Then, when you call the procedure you can use substitution variables:

```sql
BEGIN
  DBMS_OUTPUT.ENABLE();
  two(&x, &y);
END;
/
```

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/GEQy9XWf)

Answer (score 0):

You can't do this:

```
select DECODE(b,1,'True','False') into msg from dual;
```

Booleans are not part of the SQL datatypes. It's a PL/SQL-only datatype, so you can't use it in a SELECT statement. Plus, you are comparing a Boolean to an integer, which though that works in Javascript, it doesn't in SQL.

You'll have to do this:

```
IF b
THEN
  msg := 'True';
ELSE
  msg := 'False';
END IF;
```

Or don't use a Boolean.

Comment: yes but I have to do this using the decode function not if else

Comment: Then don't use a Boolean.

Comment: then what should I use